# How to detect akka-http server request timeout?

Tags: akka-http

When writing an HTTP server using akka-http’s high-level [Route API](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/index.html), is there a way to be notified that the request timeout has expired, or to check whether it is expired, or to check how much time remains? In implementing an expensive route, I would like to stop performing work on a request if the request times out.

Akka-http’s [request timeout](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/timeouts.html#request-timeout) responds to HTTP requests with status code 503 Service Unavailable: “The server was not able to produce a timely response to your request.
Please try again in a short while!” It is configured using `akka.http.server.request-timeout`, which is `20 s` by default.